# finding count of 2nd level embedded documents in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo db.

In my project I have a  requirement that I need to count the number of elements in 2nd level embedded document.

I have created a sample json which resembles the structure,

school json,

```
{
    "id": "123355",
    "name": "oxford",
    "class": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "section": [
                {
                    "id": "a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find number of sections in school name:oxford , class id 4 .

Could you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance,
Kitty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      name: "oxford"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$class"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "class.id": "4"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      count: {
        $size: {
          "$ifNull": [
            "$class.section",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3O9MehWbcOJ)

**NOTE** To flat the top level array, we use `$unwind`. If you are going to do further steps, consider grouping by `$group`